# Intent to pick a phone number from Call logs in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

How can I start an intent to pick a phone number from call logs?
I have tried using the following code to start the activity but it instead picks a phone from contacts which I don't want

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

I would appreciate any help provided

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android pick up entry from call history screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691524/android-pick-up-entry-from-call-history-screen)

Comment: Yes it does, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it cannot be done using the `ACTION.PICK`.
Try creating custom dialog with list of call logs using the content provider

[Android pick up entry from call history screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691524/android-pick-up-entry-from-call-history-screen)